# Accessing/saving new documents from VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, remote-server

Question: Can I save new documents into a folder accessed over a VPN?

Details: For one of my classes we use a SSH "MyPuTTy" in our on campus lab to access linux remote servers and code FORTRAN. I'm using VPN at home to use the campus network and gain access to MyPuTTy. I can run files I worked on on campus, but is there anyway to save new f90,txt, etc. files over it so I can write/run them via the remote server at home?